# Do Planckian EM cavities in a black body actually exist?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

I understand that, to determine the spectrum radiated by a black body at a particular temperature (say a piece of perfectly black glowing coal), we can model the object as a cavity (with an infinitesimal hole where the object is) that contains nothing but electromagnetic waves. Even though there is nothing in the cavity that has translational kinetic energy (no molecules moving about in there), we say that whatever is “in” the cavity “has” a temperature equal to the kinetic-energy temperature of the object (of say the coal). The temperature “of” the cavity is just the kinetic-energy temperature of the cavity’s walls. Right so far?

Do such cavities actually exist, or are they merely mathematical constructs, like, say, point masses?

Answer (score 1):

they were known to exist by experiment before Planck wrote his equation. for example, a little hollow cavity in the wall of a red-hot furnace appears a tiny bit brighter than the bulk of the furnace wall (because the radiation inside the cavity, being almost completely closed off, is in better thermal equilibrium with the walls of the cavity)- an effect which went unexplained until Planck came along.

Comment: can you please elaborate? If a body is in temperature T what difference does it make if the radiation comes from the outer surface or from the inner hole?

Comment: But is that really a Planckian cavity? Normally, a Planckian EM cavity is a vacuum, right? Why did that phenomenon need Planck to explain anything? Aren’t the furnace walls in the cavity just hotter than the walls in the rest of the furnace? If the walls in the furnace were a little hotter, they too would glow brighter. No?

Comment: I suggest you look up cavity radiation for a better explanation than my limited typing skills can furnish here.